# Facebook Graph API no error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am experimenting with the Facebook Graph API and have this

```
require 'sdk/autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('<MY APP ID IS HERE>', '<MY APP SECRET IS HERE>');

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://whispershare.co.za/dashboard');
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
  echo $ex;
} catch(\Exception $ex) {
  echo $ex;
}
if ($session) {
  echo 'yay';
} else echo 'boo';
```

I set the App ID and App secret but I keep getting the 'echo "boo";' on my page.
My app seems to be set up correctly. If it wasn't then it would give me an error in the try, right?

What could be wrong?

Comment: Are you actually sending the user to the login URL anywhere?

Comment: Yes I am, sorry for the delayed response.

Answer (score -1):

Please check my fb login whats is the error?
Here is the [link](https://www.hotwells.ga/login.php).

It's say -
Graph returned an error: Can not open the link: Link domain is not included in the list of gadget domains.